# Highcharts renderer in websharper

Tags: highcharts, f#, websharper

I am new to websharper and i am trying to use Highcharts.

I am able to display some nice charts and wished to add a picture.

So i found this example (and some more)

http://jsfiddle.net/F4qS8/793/

```
...
}, function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 20, 50, 30, 30)
        .add();   

});
```

And i also found the class WebSharper.Highcharts.Renderer.

But I don't see a relation between Renderer and the chart (in the WebSharper.Highcharts assembly).

I can call (static) Renderer.Image(...) but in the browser (javascript) i get an undefined (also it would't make sense since the renderer can't know where to draw, or ?).

So is there a way to get an renderer instance from the chart or let the static renderer know where to draw ? Or a different way to draw into the chart in websharper?

Comment: You fiddle doesn't work. http://www.highcharts.com/js/testing.js is not found.

Comment: Changed the link to http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. The WebSharper bindings for HighCharts are generated from the JSON API. Highsoft made some changes to the JSON structure lately, and we haven't updated for it correctly. We will look into it, in the meantime, you can use inlined JS:

```
open WebSharper
open WebSharper.JavaScript
open WebSharper.Highcharts

[<JavaScript>]
module Client =

    [<Inline "$chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 20, 50, 30, 30).add()">]
    let onComplete (chart: Chart) = ()
```

Comment: Thx i will try it later, looks ok for now.

Comment: Actually this is a bad solution IMHO. If i wish to add an img dynamically with different coordinates etc then i can't use a static string like this. I will leave the accept since it answers the question but i hope that it will be fixed in some time soon.

Comment: You can pass what you need dynamically: just replace the corresponding part of the inline string with `$foo` and add an F# function argument called `foo`, just like `chart` in @Jand's code.